# Find simple text fragment in packets

Tags: wireshark

Trying to filter packets with Wireshark. Why it finds nothing when placing `filter tcp contains M-SEARCH`. I have such value on the third line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SSDP uses UDP as the underlying transport protocol. You are filtering on TCP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol#Protocol_transport_and_addressing

Try matching UDP text instead.

Comment: I tried `UDP contains M-SEARCH`, but got the same result - `No packet contained that string in its Info column`

Comment: Might be the case that the text you see in the Info column, is not actually a field, so you can't filter on it. It's a summary of the the data form the other fields. If you view the details of the packet, you will see in which field M-SEARCH really is shown.